# How to restore Session Buddy for Chrom* sessions?

Tags: google-chrome, backup, chromium

[The Session Buddy extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/session-buddy/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko) has saved lots of important data from my browsing sessions.

I want to reinstall Ubuntu, so I'm trying to find a way to restore browser settings/history in a fresh system.

Can I just copy the extension from some folder and paste it into the appropriate folder when needed?

If so where is the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your data is saved in your chrome profile folder. To go there, type :

- `chrome://version/` in your chrome browser
- open a terminal, and navigate to the **Profile Path** given by the page mentioned above
- backup the folder : `myprofile/databases/chrome-extension_edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko_0`
- you should be able to restore it by copying to your new profile folder

[Source](http://sessionbuddy.com/datafileLocation.htm)

Answer (score 2):

Note that you will likely need to rename the database file when you port it, as Chrome auto-assigns a numeric value upon SB install. Immediately after re-installing SB, take note of the name of the database file created. Shut down Chrome and move, rename, or delete the file. Copy in your original database file and rename it to match the noted name.